# templated function with an argument that is a templated class

Tags: c++, templates

I realise there are a lot of similar questions, but I couldn't find any that solves my problem (read: I did not truly understood the answers so that I could apply it to my case)

I have the following function:

```
void printVariable(map<string, bool*>::iterator it)
{
   cout << it->first << " " << *(it->second) << endl;
}
```

Now If i have a `map<string, bool*> mapping` I can do the following: `printVariable(mapping.begin());`

This works, now I also have a a `map<string, int*>` and want to be able to do the same, so I figured I change the printVariable function:

```
template <typename T>
void printVariable(map<string, T*>::iterator it)
{
   cout << it->first << " " << *(it->second) << endl;
}
```

However this gives compile errors (gcc):

```
error: variable or field 'printVariable' declared void
error: expected ')' before 'it'
```

I guess I can work around this pretty easy by overloading the function. But I'd like to know why the above is not working.

Edit2: removed text claiming a right solution was wrong

Comment: Do you need to add a typename specifier to the parameter as the iterator is a dependent type on the template type? `void printVariable(typename map<string, T*>::iterator it)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to say `typename` to disambiguate the dependent name:

```
template <typename T>
void printVariable(typename map<string, T*>::iterator it)
//                 ^^^^^^^^
```

However, note that this is not a deducible context, so this form isn't terribly convenient.

Better yet, just make the entire iterator a template parameter:

```
template <typename Iter>
void printVariable(Iter it)
{ /* ... */ }
```

That way, you also capture maps with non-standard comparators or allocators, and unordered maps, etc. etc.

---

Here's a simple thought experiment for why you don't have a deducible context in the first situation: How should `T` be deduced in the following call of `foo`?

```
template <typename T> void foo(typename Bar<T>::type);

template <typename T> struct Bar { typedef char type; };
template <> struct Bar<int>      { typedef int type; };
template <> struct Bar<double>   { typedef int type; };

foo(10); // What is T?
```

Comment: First variant does not work indeed (I think I had already tried that also). Second variant does work however! Feel silly for not comming up with something like that to try :)

Comment: Can someone explain why the first variant doesn't work? I actual prefer that variant (if it were to work), because then the function signature is a lot clearer about what the function argument should be (or should I not consider such a thing?)

Comment: @user1302914 The first variant works in the sense that it is correct, but template argument deduction won't work (and can't be made to). Try calling it as e.g. `printVariable<bool>(it)`. Normally you should use SFINAE to make the second variant only work with `std::map`, except there's no way to link the Standard iterator types to their containers (with good reason). It's not worth worrying about.

Comment: @user1302914: You can't *deduce* the first one because it's not a deducible context. That's why you should prefer the second version.